# Swift: Benefit of using a guard-statement?

Tags: ios, swift

Just learning about the Swift `guard` keyword, I'm wondering what advantage it shall accomplish.

For example, let's say I have the following code:

```
func getEmail(email: String?) -> String {
    guard email != "" else {
        return ""
    }
    return email! + "@somewhere.com"
}

print(getEmail(email: "test123"))
```

I could write ...

```
if email == "" {
    return ""
}
return email! + "@somewhere.com"
```

... as well.

**So what's the advantage of having the guard-keyword?**

Is it just having (a little bit) of syntactic sugar?

Comment: Guard statement must have return or equivalent at else block. So, reader can be sure that code under the guard statement will be skipped if flow come at else block.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , Anton Vlasov "... improves the readability of your code ...". I think I understand it now a bit better. Thank you both!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that is a very good example of using guard, it is more common to use it with variables that might be nil (aka optional) or functions that might return nil. I suggest you read about the guard statement in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) book (just scroll down a bit to "Early Exit")

We could make a better example from your code that is lacking some validation

```
func getEmail(email: String?) -> String? {
    guard let input = email, !input.isEmpty  else {
        return nil
    }

    return input + "@somewhere.com"
}
```

Here we use guard to check that the parameter `email` is not nil by assigning it to a local variable `input`. If it is nil the function will return nil and otherwise it will check if it is empty and then it will also return.

If it is ok the function will continue and create and return an email address. Note that the function is declared to return an optional string since I think it is much clearer if a function like this returns nil rather than an empty string if it fails.

Comment: IMO this is a very good anti-example. The function clearly says that it does not make any sense to pass `nil` as an argument because there's nothing to do with `nil` value.

So IMO this is a case when `email` arg should be converted to a non-optional.

Comment: @storoj The question is about how to use `guard` on an optional parameter so that is what the answer is about. Your solution is more of a code review of the actual function.

Comment: the question was "what's the advantage?". And my comment is saying that it's possibly a _disadvantage_.

Answer (score 3):

Guard statement is early exit statement the main use of guard statement is to transfer program control out of a scope on certain conditions. These statements are similar with if statements which executes statements based on certain condition but unlike if, the guard statements only run when certain conditions are not met.
i strongly recommended to read this article [Swift guard statement](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/)

Answer (score 2):

If your code needs to decide whether to exit early, then you use the guard construct. A guard statement consists of a condition and an else block. The ***else*** block must leave the current scope, by any of the means that Swift provides, such as **return**, **break**, **continue**, **throw**, or **fatalError**. In case of failure of the condition, execution absolutely will not proceed within the block that contains the guard construct. Most of the time the construct is used to check Optional values, similar to *if let* statement. Unlike *if let* and/or *while let*, *guard let* doesn’t declare the bound variable for a nested scope, it declares it for *this* scope. Guys gave good examples on their answers about that. I would like to pay more attention on other possible cases as well.

A guard construct will also come in handy in conjunction with ***try?***. Let’s presume we can’t proceed unless *String(contentsOfFile:)* succeeds. Then we can do the following:

```
guard let text = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else {return}
```

There is also a ***guard case*** construct, forming the logical inverse of *if case*, e.g.:

```
guard case let .number(n) = error else { return }
```

There is one more interesting problem that you can solve using *guard case* construct. Suppose we have a function whose returned value we want to check in a *guard* statement:

```
guard howMany() > 10 else { return }
```

All looks good, but suppose that in the next line you want to use the value returned from that function. You may not want to call that function over again, because that might be time-consuming or it may have any side effects. You can't capture the result of calling the function with with *guard let*, because that requires an Optional, and the function *howMany()* doesn’t return an Optional.
In this case, you can use *guard case* construct in following way:

```
guard case let amount = howMany(), amount > 10 else { return }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think for email id it would be that beneficial,

> But consider example where there is a function where among students,
>   for one student you have to perform some crucial operation but what if
>   the student does not exist then there is no point in doing anything so
>   there comes your here as early exist which you can do using guard
>   statement.

```
let student = studentArr.filter{$0.id == "1234"}

guard let stdnt = student[0], stdnt != nil  else {
    return nil
}

// calculate marks of this student for all years' maths subject to prepare analytics
```

Comment: `filter()[0]` => `first(where:)`. `filter` checks **whole** sequence for the condition, `first(where:)` checks only until it finds an item that satisfy condition. If your `sequence` is big or even infinite you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> if let and guard let serve similar, but distinct purposes.
>
> The "else" case of guard must exit the current scope. Generally that
>   means it must call return or abort the program. guard is used to
>   provide early return without requiring nesting of the rest of the
>   function.
>
> if let nests its scope, and does not require anything special of it.
>   It can return or not.
>
> In general, if the if-let block was going to be the rest of the
>   function, or its else clause would have a return or abort in it, then
>   you should be using guard instead. This often means (at least in my
>   experience), when in doubt, guard is usually the better answer. But
>   there are plenty of situations where if let still is appropriate.